# in chrome, if width of element inside div is 100% than second one push above

Tags: jquery, css, html, google-chrome

I have two element inside a div. First one is select , second one is input. I want to input cover the select. I am succesfull in IE10 and Firefox. But Html is not as desired as well in Chrome. 
IE and Firefox it seems like:

[image: FireFox and IE10]

[image: Chrome]

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  setclerablecombotext();
})

function setclerablecombotext() {
  var sample = $("#mycombo");
  var wt = sample.width();
  var ht = sample.height();
  $('.clearable').width(wt - 20);
  $('.clearable').css('margin-left', -(wt + 4));
}
```

```css
.clearable {
  border: none;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="background-color:blue;width:500px;">
  <select id="mycombo" style="width:100%;display:inline;background-color:red;border:none;">
     <option>TEST0</option>
     <option>TEST1</option>
   </select>
  <input value="This is input" class="clearable" />
</div>
```

If I set width of select is 99% , I works. But It will seems bad.

Comment: It's most likely a default style that differs from browser to browser.  I'd strongly recommend searching for a css reset stylesheet.  That should ensure a consistent start point for all browsers (if it's any good).

Comment: what do you mean by "input covering the select "

Comment: @SuprajaGanji, I mean editable combobox. When I select from combobox , It will append to input

Comment: I'd suggest using a proper input/dropdown JS control. Hacking together a couple of form inputs like this won't work very well across browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your html and css is not really clear. So I created this fiddle.

Is this what you want?

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
<select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
<input type="text" placeholder="Write something here">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper{
  width: 50%;
  position: relative;
}

.wrapper select,
.wrapper input{
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper select{
  width: 100%;
}

.wrapper input{
  width: calc(100% - 30px)
}

.wrapper input{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/unsx8L9o/

Comment: Note that while this seems ok on Windows, it doesn't work at all on OSX: https://i.imgur.com/WVrLQBp.png

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan does not work at all is exaggeration. In that case you just add to 'select' the height of input box.

Answer (score 1):

Even though I am not sure this is useful approach in the first place, the problem is that Chrome applies a linebreak. Use `white-space: nowrap` on the div above the select and input.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  setclerablecombotext();
})

function setclerablecombotext() {
  var sample = $("#mycombo");
  var wt = sample.width();
  var ht = sample.height();
  $('.clearable').width(wt - 20);
  $('.clearable').css('margin-left', -(wt + 4));
}
```

```css
.clearable {
  border: none;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="background-color:blue;width:500px;white-space:nowrap;">
  <select id="mycombo" style="width:100%;display:inline;background-color:red;border:none;">
     <option>TEST0</option>
     <option>TEST1</option>
   </select>
  <input value="This is input" class="clearable" />
</div>
```